# What is invalid about this header: Accept: */*; q=0.5; application/json

Tags: http, asp.net-core

My app makes a post to an aspnetcore controller.

It is throwing this error message:

```
FormatException: "Invalid values '*/*; q=0.5; application/json'."
```

I don't see what is wrong with it.

This is the raw post:

```
POST /api/attachments/save HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 130897
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: */*; q=0.5; application/json
Origin: http://localhost:4000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryDBTUPFcCjjuB8Z1p
Referer: http://localhost:4000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ai_user=7qQV6|2016-06-29T23:52:02.982Z
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `,` instead of `;` before `application/json`:

```
Accept: */*; q=0.5, application/json
```

Syntax and semantics of standard HTTP/1.1 header fields are described in [Header Field Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

Comment: Does the `q=0.5, application/json` even make sense?  How can json have quality? I am using a component, and the component code has this specified in the accept type.

Comment: above should be interpreted as "I prefer application/json, but send me any media type if it is the best available after an 50% mark-down in quality."

Comment: Correct, but you're citing an obsolete spec. See https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#header.accept instead.